# Dynamically Get and Set Properties on an EF Core Model

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I'm learning C# and trying to find out how I can have a common method for updating different addresses that inherit from Address, and have an address type discriminator - PhysicalAddress and MailingAddress.

The example shows what I'd like to do if I could array access properties on models like you would in TypeScript. It indicates what I'm trying to do and have accomplished using two methods, but I haven't been able to figure out the way to achieve this in C#.

Any help, direction, or URL for referencing would be great.  If this is not a good way to set up an update what would a properly single method update that would work with PerformUpdate.

```c
// Example of an actual update method:
public async Task<int> PerformUpdate(User user, User updateUser) {
  UpdateAddress(user, updateUser.PhysicalAddress);
  UpdateAddress(user, updateUser.MailingAddress);

  return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}

// Example of what I would like to achieve:
private void UpdateAddress(User user, Address newAddress)
{
    // Currently would be: PhysicalAddress or MailingAddress
    var addressType = newAddress.GetType().ToString();

    // Dynamically access the address on the user based on the address type
    Address oldAddress = user[addressType];
    
    // Remove the old and add the new
    if(oldAddress != null) {
        _context.Addresses.Remove(oldAddress);
    }

    user[addressType] = newAddress;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the use case for this first, unless you have to support a truly huge number of classes it's probably better to create setters explicitly for each class you wish to support, for example with the `is` keyword. However, since you asked, we can abuse reflection to achieve this like so:

````cs
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var address = new PhysicalAddress();
            var user = new User();
            
            // this will set user.Address1 to address
            SetAddress(user, address);

        }

        public static void SetAddress(User user, Address newAddress)
        {
            var fields = typeof(User).GetFields();

            foreach (var fieldInfo in fields)
            {
                if (fieldInfo.FieldType == newAddress.GetType())
                {
                    fieldInfo.SetValue(user, newAddress);
                }
            }
        }

        
    }

    class User
    {
        public PhysicalAddress Address1;
        public WorkAdress Address2;
    }

    class Address
    {

    }

    class PhysicalAddress: Address
    {

    }

    class WorkAdress: Address
    {

    }
```
````